# Wkhtmlpdf quality of charts

Tags: canvas, charts, wkhtmltopdf

From time I use wkhtmltopdf to create PDFs. Everything is fine except pie charts drawn on the canvas.

I would add that the animations are disabled. Below write settings wkhtmltopdf. I tried different DPI settings and image quality.

no-stop-slow-scripts = true, javascript-delay = 3000, image-dpi => 600, image-quality = 100, disable-smart-shrinking = true, lowquality = null

PDF:
[image: in pdf]

HTML:
[image: on site]

Answer (score 2):

there is a --dpi parameter in the general section (not page related). I resolved a similar problem by setting `--dpi 600`